# Assign address as literal to pointer?

Tags: c++

Since the value of a pointer is a memory address, like 0x0224, can you somehow assign an address given as a literal to a pointer? I have tried by assigning an integer literal to a pointer, but that did not really work out very well, as you can probably guess.

Comment: Are you asking how to do `some_type* some_name = 1234;`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish? something like `Object *obj = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(0x0224)`?

Comment: Are you interested in the *mechanism of assignment* of some value or in the *value being assigned* itself? Curious answers the former and I answer the latter.

Comment: @JuanRamirez Yup :) And yes Nathan, that is what I am asking but also why you have to do something extra for the literal to be treated as an address(I have asked this as a comment to Curious' answer).

Comment: Because it is not permitted by the C++ standard, even when such non-conformant code is allowed by some compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `reinterpret_cast`

```
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x123);
```

Comment: Ahh okay, that is what I was going for, thank you. But why do you have to use a cast in order for it to work/for it to treat to literal as an address? And does this work just like you would think? Like, in your example, `ptr` would simply be assigned the address `0x123`?

Comment: The cast is required because a literal of that form is of type `int`, and an `int` is not convertible (without a `reinterpret_cast`) to a `void*`.  And this does work as you would think yes.  Just be careful when using negative integers and the like.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. But why would you not just use C-cast or static_cast?

Comment: @FacPam `static_cast` wouldn't work and C style casts are bad style in C++

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this to your heart's content. Operating systems that isolate processes' memory spaces will typically terminate your program if you happen to try to access memory outside your process's allocated memory space, but as long as the value you're assigning is one that your process is allowed to access, you can read and write (possibly subject to some additional restrictions).

As pointed out in the comments, the question may also refer to the *how* of actually performing such an assignment. This is covered well in other answers. The short answer is that you should cast the literal to a pointer value of the appropriate type.

Comment: This answer is helpful but doesn't address *how* to achieve this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Looking at the other answers I think I see the other interpretation of the question: *somehow* referring to the actual mechanism of assignment. I attached *somehow* to the *literal* instead. I will leave this answer as the other attachment is well-covered elsewhere; this provides guidance on *how* to pick a literal. I suppose this is my interpretation since it seems like trying a cast would be natural when the compiler complains and a simple C-style cast, the first thing a novice would try, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the value of a pointer is a memory address, like 0x0224, can you
>   somehow assign an address given as a literal to a pointer?

I think the answer for your desktop is 'no'.

The value of a pointer in a user process is to a virtual memory address.  Though the address exists virtually and therefore mapped to physical memory, it does not reveal a physical address, in particular, the physical might be different for each run of the app.

So, maybe the issue is how to discover, for use at compile time, a specific address with which to create a literal that is repeatable.  How do you find out what (?virtual) memory you might be able to access on your next run?

On my desktop, I think I can not.

---

So, let me provide an example from my embedded systems work in the telecom industry.  I think you will find it is about what your question suggests, when your code has access to physical memory mapped devices.

I will skip down to the shelf computer level, here called the mcu.

The mcu has multiple logic devices. In this snippet, we randomly choose to inspect pci2 (first thing I found)

```
class mcu_pci2_t  // all reg's 32 bit
{
  public:
     mcu_pci2_t(void){};
     ~mcu_pci2_t(void){/*always implement*/};

  enum MCU_PCI2_CONSTRAINTS
  {         
     MCU_PCI2_ADDR     = 0x80000000LU,                 // 0x8000 0000
     //
     ...
     //
     MC_SRBL_FPGA_ADDR = MCU_PCI2_ADDR + 0x08000000LU, // 0x8800 0000
     //
     MC_PCI2_CONSTRAINTS_END
  };
```

Next, we will look closer at the MC_SRBL_FPGA_ADDR.  The hardware logic on the mcu starts at address 0x8000,0000LU, and the SRBL starts at 0x8800,0000. I've removed many of these entries, too.

```
enum MC_SRBL_CONSTRAINTS
{
   CRXX_LED_ADDR            = MC_SRBL_FPGA_ADDR + 0x00000004, // 0x8100 0004 red,off        Bit0
...
   //
   FAN_LMPTEST_ADDR         = MC_SRBL_FPGA_ADDR + 0x00000040, // 0x8800 0040 normal/test    Bit0
   //
...
//
```

Now we skip down to how the code uses FAN_LMPTEST_ADDR.

```
class fan_lmptest_t
{
public: 
   fan_lmptest_t(void){};
   ~fan_lmptest_t(void){/*always implement*/};

   // returns 0 when successful
   const char* change(bool on,   bool sim=false);

   uint32_t value(void) { uint32_t ret_val = reg(); return(ret_val); };

private:
   inline vuint32_t& reg(void) { 
      return(*(reinterpret_cast<vuint32_t*>(FAN_LMPTEST_ADDR))); 
   };

private: // coding standard: when not used, make NOT accessible AND do NOT implement
   fan_lmptest_t(const fan_lmptest_t&);            // copy constructor    X(const X&)
   fan_lmptest_t& operator= (const fan_lmptest_t&);// copy assignment     X& operator= (const X&)
};
```

Here we see that the enum physical address value is cast into a pointer

```
reinterpret_cast<vuint32_t*>(FAN_LMPTEST_ADDR);
```

In this case, vuint32_t means the compiler is commanded to treat the data at this address as "volatile uint32_t".

(fyi - the change() method is implemented in a .cc file else where.)

Operationally, the user interface code that decides to activate or deactivate lamptest is quite some distance from this code.  What it does is turn on or off the full fan.  Apparently, fan is part of lamp-test.  Its all good.

This is very much like you suggest in your question ... a literal (i.e. an enum) can be cast to a physical address, and if the address maps correctly to the hardware, eureka! we have fan.

---

FYI - That embedded operating system is OSE by ONEA. The mcu is based on some ppc derivative, don't remember which one.  The hardware mapped memory uses a dedicated 32 bit wide hw bus, but the code and stack and heap reside in the dram memory, with a reasonable cache, and a 64 bits wide buss.